# Running a robot file based on git commit in jenkins

Tags: python, jenkins, robotframework

I am currently building a robotframework using python for my project. The structure of robotframework is

```
-Parent Folder

 -Folder 1

   -Robot1.robot

   -Robot2.robot

 -Folder 2

   -Robot3.robot

   -Robot4.robot
```

In my current implementation, when i commit changes to Robot1.robot, the jenkins creates a build and it runs all the robot file.

I wanted to have a way/process that if i make changes to Robot1.robot, the jenkins build runs only Robot1.robot. Is there is a way to run the changed/updated robot file?

Regards,

Prasanna

Comment: if you are using webhooks from github check https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#push

But basically you can get the same effect with the SCM plugin in jenkins using filters to get the commited file.

Answer (score 0):

For getting file changes you can use below command, it will return the file changes since last commit.

```
git diff --name-only HEAD HEAD~1
```

Store the Output to a variable and and then run the loop on file names stored in variable.

If you are using freestyle projects in Jenkins, it will be a good idea to write a small script which can do this, and just call the script from Jenkins.